# Why can't I remove social icons on mobile version even if I uninstalled WP-Socializer Plugin?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

1)My problem is related to the mobile version of WordPress. When I installed **Access Press social sharing plugin** for social sharing and deactivated and deleted it when I didn't want it, it still appears in my mobile version of the website.

I can see it on my mobile and brother's too that the icons appear. But my friend says he can't see the icons whereas I can see it on my mobile, even if I have uninstalled the plugin.

2) I had also installed **Wp-socializer** plugin and deactivated and deleted it, but when I see on the mobile version and go to the desktop view from my mobile, I can still see it. I don't know what's the problem?

3)Please tell me what should I do to completely remove the icons from the mobile version. Should I use any plugin like **w3cache**? If yes then how will it solve my problem? This is my site ( https://unveilmycareer.com). Go and see on the mobile and also go to desktop view to see my problem.

4) I am attaching screenshots too.

[Screenshot 1 of access press social share plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQfdt.jpg)
[Screenshot 2 of Wp-socializer plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZOIB.jpg)

Comment: clear your browser cache and update your permalink

Comment: Hey I did cleared my cache on my browser, but still it appears! How updating my permalink will affect any plugin?

Comment: See page source by ctrl + u , its shows the socializer js //cdn.rawgit.com/vaakash/socializer/aaa23968/css/socializer.min.css?ver=4.9.8, Check your theme functions.php file have you add any custom code

Comment: bro I did not added any custom code. In chrome I cant see any icons but in firefox I do see. I dont whats the problem. I also cleared browser and site cache using w3 super cache and auto optimize plugin. still the problem exists.

Comment: Thanks for your time. My issue has been solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must installl cache plugin and clear cache
 - you can use Wp Faster Cache
   It has a icon whem you install to the horizontal bar, the icon has a lebel Clear Cash

after you must delete history from browser

Good luck